# Запятые в приложениях

Tags: запятые, приложение

**Дважды Герой Советского Союза, Герой Монгольской Народной Республики генерал армии Исса Плиев отважно сражался на фронтах Великой Отечественной войны**

Объясните, пожалуйста,популярно это правило про однородные/неоднородные приложения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Дважды Герой Советского Союза* и *Герой Монгольской республики* — однородные члены, а именно наградные звания. Мы можем их сгруппировать.

*Генерал армии* не является третьим однородным, потому что характеризует человека с другой стороны — воинского звания.